# Variable itemize indentation on Beamer slides

Tags: beamer, lists, indentation, itemize

I'm not sure if what I want is possible at all, but asking doesn't hurt...

I've adjusted the `itemize` environment so that the item text is aligned with the text outside the environment. This might look strange, but since I never use itemized and non-itemized text on the same slide, it's not a problem.

A problem arises if I use `itemize` inside a `block` environment. In this case, the bullets are positioned outside of the box -- which is definitely not what I want.

Can I somehow distinguish between `itemize` environments inside a block and the ones outside a block and set the `\leftmargini` accordingly?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    This is a text.
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This is an item.
      \item This is another item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item with a subitem
        \item and another subitem
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
    \begin{alertblock}{Just A Block}
      This is a text in a block.
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This is an item in a block.
        \item Another item.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{alertblock}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Where do I get this cuuute pink color theme?

Comment: @mbork You need a `crane` to lift it...

Comment: Well, `crane` is rather orange-ish, I'd say.  (I know that because it's one of my favorite beamer color themes, not counting my own one;).)

Comment: @mbork This is just an alert block - I used it for no special purpose, my actual slides are rather greenish...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the following do what you want? My solution redefines the `alertblock` environment so that `\leftmargini` be reset to its original value at the beginning of the environment; outside of an `alertblock`'s scope, `\leftmargini` reverts to its global value. You can of course adapt the method to other environments, if you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\newlength\origleftmargini
\setlength\origleftmargini\leftmargini
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}}

\let\oldalertblock\alertblock
\let\oldendalertblock\endalertblock
\def\alertblock{\begingroup \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{\origleftmargini}} \oldalertblock}
\def\endalertblock{\oldendalertblock \endgroup}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    This is a text.
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This is an item.
      \item This is another item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item with a subitem
        \item and another subitem
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
    \begin{alertblock}{Just A Block}
    %\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{\origleftmargini}}
      This is a text in a block.
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This is an item in a block.
        \item Another item.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{alertblock}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This is an item.
      \item This is another item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item with a subitem
        \item and another subitem
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can place code in `block alerted begin` to adjust material contained in that block.  In this case, one way to acheive your goal is to redefine `\@listi`.  The definition below is beamer's standard definition with just the setting of `\leftmargin` to `\leftmargini` changed to `3em`.  Adjust this value as you wish.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{
\def\@listi{\leftmargin3em
  \topsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2.5\p@
  \parsep 0\p@
  \itemsep3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus3\p@}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is a text.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item This is an item.
  \item This is another item
    \begin{itemize}
    \item with a subitem
    \item and another subitem
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{alertblock}{Just A Block}
    This is a text in a block.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item in a block.
    \item Another item.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{alertblock}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item This is an item.
  \item This is another item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As the code involved uses internal variables containing `@` it has to be enclosed in a `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair.